# Cleaning dynamic memory of linked objects

Tags: c++, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation

I need to clean up the dynamic memory of linked objects. I'm studying branch & bound algorithm for an optimization problem. I have a class called "node" that keeps data of partial solution. I create the nodes using "new" function. All created nodes are linked to each other forming a chain like I created a manuel list. Each node knows the physical address of the best node that comes after it. This chain is dynamic. Using existing nodes I generate new nodes and link them to the chain accordingly till I find the optimal solution. For some problems I find the optimal solution when number of nodes are about 3 billion (30-40 GB). I set my code to pass to solve the next problem when it finishes to solve one (I do this by multiple file streaming during process). I need to free up the memory before passing to solve another problem. I tried to use "delete" function when I find the optimal and when I no more need the node chain. The bad thing is deleting 3 billion node objects linked to each other takes hours. I am terminating the program, remove the file of the solved one from the directory, wait windows to free the RAM and then restart it again to continue my work.
Is there a way to free up the memory while passing to another problem to solve like the cleaning operation the termination process does, or should I change the structure of the node chain?

Answer (score 3):

Sound like a job for a customized new which allocates from a pool you can deallocate.

```
class Node
{
    void* operator new(size_t bytes);
    void delete(void* ptr) {}
    ...
};
```

Now your operator new can do this

```
char* big_block = new char[100000];
char* free_ptr = big_block;

void* Node::operator new(size_t bytes)
{
    char* ptr = free_ptr;
    free_ptr += bytes;
    return ptr;
}
```

Then when you're done you can just call `delete[] big_block;` and all your memory is freed. Something like that anyway. There are some details to add.

Comment: Shouldn't it be void* Node::operator new(size_t bytes)?
You also forgot to add operator before delete.

Answer (score 2):

If you have 3 billion objects, you need to free 3 billion objects. Except, if you cheat.

One way of cheating is killing the process, as you've already correctly pointed out. Of course that rules out doing something else afterwards.

Another way would be to overload `operator new` to use a block allocator and `operator delete` to do nothing (or forget `operator delete` alltogether). The block allocator would allocate one huge block (or maybe several ones on demand, those could be in a linked list) from which the objects you allocate are being drawn. This can be implemented in a relatively trivial way (returning an element from an array, and incrementing the index).

Then, when you are done with your 3 billion objects, call a function in your block allocator that simply throws away entire blocks at a time (deallocating them). The allocator does not know about the 3 billion objects and doesn't care. All it does is one (or maybe 3-4) large deallocations.

Answer (score 0):

Use the destructor to free resources allocated by constructors, or additional resources allocated by mutators.

Comment: If he uses delete, the destructor will be called automatically. His point is, that this process takes way too long for his application.